# How to capture raw audio samples after every 10MS using FFmpeg programmatically?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, encoding, webrtc, opus

I am using **FFmpeg** to record audio using **pulse audio** at a `48k sampling` rate and `32k bitrate`. Eventually, I perform encoding these recorded samples through opus which is configured on default settings such as `frame_size set to 120`, `initial padding set to 120` and etc. I am not sure about the recording callback settings for pulse audio but I have read in opus RFC that it uses `120ms` by default and can support `10, 20, 40, 60`, and any other which is a `multiple of 2.5`.

I have a project where I have added **WebRTC p2p connection** support to send **FFmpeg** recorded audio/video on the audio/video channel of WebRTC to the next connected peer. In the case of sending plain audio as well as plain video which is recorded through FFmpeg, there is no issue with sending these over an audio/video channel (obviously) however, in the case of FFmpeg encoded data, **I have to modify WebRTC audio/video encoder factories (clear to me).**

I want to capture raw audio samples using FFmpeg after every **10MS callback.**

Comment: Is it 10 megasamples or 10 milliseconds? Either way, run ffmpeg perpetually to pipe raw audio samples (e.g., `pcm_s16le`) out to a webworker (I'm not a JS guy so my terminology might be off) which manages the buffer and sends out 10MS worth of samples whenever requested. FFmpeg itself is ill-suited to do on-demand actions like that.

Comment: WebRTC is expected to get raw audio from mic using Pulse or ALSA, encode it to OPUS (or whatever else) and send to another peer. If I understood you correctly, you want to send OPUS audio which is encoded by your own. Then yes, you'll have to modify WebRTC, in particular create "fake" audio encoder and your own audio encoder factory, which will create the encoder.

Comment: @ArtemSuprunov I am looking into the solution of building a "fake" audio encoder and factory. Currently, My Audio is being played by WebRtc very fast because the recording from Opus is on 120ms and WebRtc uses 10ms.

Comment: I have a doubt that it's possible to use 120 ms length without significant modifying Google WebRTC sources, because whole pipeline is built assuming 10 ms. The thing is not only in encoder. Even if you create fake encoder, its Encode() method will be called for 10 ms portion data, look at this description https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/refs/heads/master/api/audio_codecs/audio_encoder.h#144
So you would need to change rtp packetizing part of the pipeline. And then probably on the receiving side also changes are needed, but I'm not sure about this.